# setting UITableView separator inset to zero is not working

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, xcode6

I define my table entirely in code. I want to remove the padding in the separator but my trials are not working

```
  [tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero]
```

and

```
  [tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
```

Comment: Actually further testing shows that the padding is present until after I call `reload` on the table.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
[tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 10)];
```

Comment: This does not solve the original problem, but it centers the separator which is symmetrical. So that's acceptable for me. Thanks. +1

Comment: can u show the screen shot, then I know which type u need , after i change my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the left margin/padding by setting the frame's x margin into negative.

`MyTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-5, 108, 325, 500);`

Answer (score 0):

You want to remove separator? If yes then instead of applying inset use Table view property

```
[self.tblResults setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
```

Comment: I don't want to remove the separator. I want to remove the left margin/padding